# Такой цикл может быть в C#?

Tags: c#

```
for (int j=0,i = 1, k = 2;(j < n)^ (i < n)^ (k < n) ;j+=3,i+=3,k+=3) { }
```

Случайно где-то нашел , но найти заново эту программу я не смогу.

Comment: А что собсно не нравится? если не считать того, что _**n**_ должно было быть определено ранее...

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Скомпилируется ли ваш код? Ну так возьмите и попробуйте!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (int j=0, i=1, k=2; (j<n) ^ (i<n) ^ (k<n); j+=3, i+=3, k+=3)
> ```

Да, цикл может иметь такой вид. Выполняется до тех пор, пока истинно нечётное количество условий. Т. е. нечётное количество переменных строго меньше `n`.

Comment: экое забористое условие, интересно зачем такое могло понадобиться...

Comment: а что значит перевёрнутый треугольник?

Comment: @АлексейКряжев А это друг называется оператором логического исключающего ИЛИ

Comment: А почему этот треугольник перевёрнут? о_О Вроде наоборот, прямой.